# MySQL multiple columns in ALL clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

Why it is not allowed to do the following?

```sql
SELECT Column_1
FROM Mytable
WHERE (Column_1, Column_2) >= ALL(SELECT Column_1,Column_2 FROM MYTABLE2)
```

But it is possible to do

```sql
SELECT Column_1
FROM Mytable
WHERE (Column_1, Column_2) IN (SELECT Column_1,Column_2 FROM MYTABLE2)
```

Comment: Your subquery has two `from` clause, so this won't even compile.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: All things are possible. For specific help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ...what do you expect `>= ALL(...)` to _do?_ You can't just make up syntax.

Comment: It's not allowed as MySQL does not support it. If you want to extend the SQL dialect used by MySQL, you're welcome to do so - but that might be more difficult than using a different query syntax that is already supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the query you wanted to write:

```
select col1 from t1 where (col1, col2) > all(select col1, col2 from t2);
```

This does not work in MySQL, and raises error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

MySQL supports tuple (in)equality though, so you could phrase this with `not exists`:

```
select col1 
from t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t2
    where (t2.col1, t2.col2) > (t1.col1, t1.col2)
)
```